# TypedJs Library gives DevTools error in browser console

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, typedjs

So I'm working through adding the TypedJS library to a Node web app I'm working on.  I installed it to my project through npm.  Here's it's entry in the package.json dependencies section:

```
"typed.js": "^2.0.11"
```

Here's the CDN script tag present at the bottom of the HTML body:

```
        <!-- Typed.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.11"></script>
```

After installing through npm and including the CDN script tag, everything works as expected; however, I get this error in the console:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, 
net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

What am I missing here?  I'd rather not have this error present on each page load for TypedJS.  Thanks in advance for the help